# How to set form field focus on page load in EWL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, focus, enterprise-web-library

I want to set focus to a particular form field on page load. This will be the same form field every time the page is loaded, even after posting-back a data modification. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Override `EwfPage.controlWithInitialFocus`. This property is called after `LoadData`.